# Href link to google map marker from outside the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website with google map embedded in it, and there is a div with a set of hrefs which I would like to point to certain coordinates on the map.

I have searched online but couldn't find much help.
I don't want to open the lat and long in another window using something like this - https://www.google.com/maps/?q=-15.623037,18.388672

If you see the image below, I want to have links in the div on the right(links will be fetched dynamically), and those links will point to the markers on the map and display an info window

Any help is appreciated thanks.[image]

Comment: You have to keep references to those marker object and access it depending on which link that's clicked. When you have accessed the marker object then you can do whatever you like using Marker API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When creating markers, add them

> custom 'id'

data to be able to find them later:

```
var marker0 = createMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    map: map,
    id: "m0",
    icon: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png"
  });
```

2. Push all markers into array:

`markers.push(marker0);`

3. Generate links based on markers array and add

> custom 'id'

to them:

```
function fillLinks(){
    var d1 = document.getElementById('markers_div');
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {  
        d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<a href="#" onclick="linkClick(\''+marker["id"]+'\')">'+marker["id"]+'</a><br/>');
  });
}
```

4. When clicking the link, use custom 'id' to center map based on lat and lng of marker:

   ```
   function linkClick(markerId){
       for (let marker of markers) {
          if(marker['id'] == markerId){    
             center(marker.getPosition().lat(), marker.getPosition().lng() );
             marker.info.open(map, marker);     
          } else {
             marker.info.close(map, marker);
          }
       }
   }

   function center(lat, lng){
       map.setCenter({lat:lat, lng:lng});
   }
   ```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/3315/

Comment: Thank you Ivan, this is close to what I want to achieve, this gave me a good start to go... Thanks again.